# problem when trying to load data with textscan

Tags: octave, textscan

I want to load a set of data that contains variables type string and float. But when I use textscan in octave, my data doesn't load. I got matrix 1x6 (i have 6 features), but in this matrix I got cells that contains nothing(cells that are 0x1).
my code:

```
filename='data1.txt';
fileID = fopen(filename,'r');
data = textscan(fileID,'%f %s %s %f %f %s','Delimiter',',');
fclose(fileID);
```

when I for example try data(1):

```
 >> data(1)
ans =
{
  [1,1] = [](0x1)
}

>>
```

[there is it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfGG9.png)

[there is my set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJkyD.png)

Also my file id isn't -1.

I had been searching for in the ethernet problem like this but I couldn't find any.
I tried to delete headers in data and smaller training set but it don't work.
Pls help.

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: The screenshot is showing fid=3. Why are you telling us about it not being -1?  Did you try adding a newline character \n to the end of the format string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use textscan. Textscan is horrible, and one should only use it when they're trying to parse data when there's no better way available.

*Your* data is a standard csv file. Just use `csv2cell` from the `io` package.